# How to calculate length of nested JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Here I load a JSON into a variable. But I am unable to find the length of the nested JSON.

```
var JVarible = [{"key":{"kind":"Comment","id":5992578889547776},"categoryId":0,"userName":"Shana Deepak","userId":"cpshana","comment":"hi.fghfghfgh ","createDate":"Sep 16, 2013 7:07:36 AM","url":"https://graph.facebook.com/100000840303512/picture?type\u003dsmall","networkType":"facebook","status":1,"nestmsgs":{"value":"[{\"key\":{\"kind\":\"Nestmsg\",\"id\":5914238686068736},\"commentId\":5992578889547776,\"userName\":\"Shana Deepak\",\"userId\":\"cpshana\",\"message\":\"dfgdfgfdg\",\"createDate\":\"Sep 16, 2013 7:22:01 AM\",\"url\":\"https://graph.facebook.com/100000840303512/picture?type\\u003dsmall\",\"networkType\":\"facebook\",\"status\":0},{\"key\":{\"kind\":\"Nestmsg\",\"id\":5281469744283648},\"commentId\":5992578889547776,\"userName\":\"Shana Deepak\",\"userId\":\"cpshana\",\"message\":\"gfdgdfgfd\",\"createDate\":\"Sep 16, 2013 7:12:25 AM\",\"url\":\"https://graph.facebook.com/100000840303512/picture?type\\u003dsmall\",\"networkType\":\"facebook\",\"status\":0}]"}}];


var i=0;

 for (i=0; i<JVarible.length;i++)
 {

 alert(JVarible[i].['nestmsgs'].length)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `JVarible` does not contain JSON. It contains a JavaScript **array**. But one of the values inside that array is indeed JSON (contained in a string).

Your question is not very clear, but it seems you want to get the number of messages within each object. `nestmsgs` is actually an object with one property, `value`. `value` has a string containing JSON as value.

You first have to parse the JSON, which results in an array, and then you can determine its length:

```
for (var i = 0; i < JVarible.length; i++) {
    var msgobj = JVarible[i].nestmsgs;
    msgobj.value = JSON.parse(msgobj.value);
    alert(msgobj.value.length)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Object.keys(JVarible[0]) //returns ["key", "categoryId", "userName", "userId", "comment", "createDate", "url", "networkType", "status", "nestmsgs"]

Object.keys(JVarible[0]).length //returns 10
```